# Hex Dump Specific Parts of File - Bash

Tags: bash, hexdump

I'm trying to write a bash script to audit hard drives that have been wiped to ensure the wiping system is working properly.  I would like to find a way to hex dump specific parts of a drive without having to hex dump the entire drive and extract the parts I'd like (as this seems to run for too long to make the script worth writing). Ideally, I'd be able to grab parts from the beginning, middle, and end of the drive.

I would like to take the output of the hex dump and check it for the existence of only one character (indicating the drive has been successfully wiped).  This part, I can handle, but I thought it may affect any advice I may get.

I've used head piped into xxd to get the beginning of the file which has worked, but I'm still stuck on the other parts.  I've tried using tail to just get the end of the drive, but that doesn't seem to work quickly either.  Is it possible to do this efficiently?  Possibly using dd or something else and pipe it into a hex editor?  I've looked through options for xxd as well as hexdump to no avail.  If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not look at getting SeaTools for DOS? www.seagate.com

Answer (score 3):

xxd has options to skip a ways into the file (`-s`) and dump a limited length (`-l`). If you use its plain hex (`-p`) option, you may be able to use grep to find any anomalies:

```
$ xxd -s 8192 -l 256 -p /dev/disk3s2 | grep [^0]
000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000300000000000000800000000000000000000
dbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdb
dbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdb
dbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdbdb
```

`od` has similar skip (`-j`) and limit length (`-N`). Similarly, `dd` has `skip=` and `count=` (although these are counted in blocks, not bytes; you can change the block size with `bs=`).

EDIT: Since `xxd -p` is giving weird results (not stopping at what should be the end of the device), I'd recommend running some tests to figure out what's going on. First, **back up anything important on the computer**, because if something is weird at the device access level, it's possible that some of these tests might overwrite something unexpected, possibly even on another disk.

Next, try dumping to the end of the device with different tools, and see if they all behave the same way:

```
xxd -s 65451982336 /dev/sdb | more  # This *should* dump 512 bytes (32 lines) then stop, but apparently keeps going
od -xv -j 65451982336 /dev/sdb | more  # This also *should* dump 512 bytes then stop
dd if=/dev/sdb skip=127835903 | xxd | more # This again should do the same thing (note that the skip value is in 512-byte blocks)
```

Do the other tools read past what fdisk reports as the end of the disk? If all three read more data, I'm going with the "fdisk is wrong/misleading" answer. You can test further by writing some nonzero data past the "end" and seeing what the results are:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/sdb seek=127835903 count=2
```

...then repeat the various dump commands. If they show two blocks (=64 lines) of random data followed by zeroes, I'm pretty sure the device is bigger than you think it is.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused; I'd like to take the size of a drive (in bytes), subtract some amount from that number, then go from that point to the end of the drive.  For example, I'm currently using a flash drive attached to my system (at /dev/sdb) which `fdisk -l` lists as being 65451982848 bytes.  If I run `xxd -s 65451982847 -p /dev/sdb` it seems to run indefinitely, although it is only one byte from the end.  Is there a way to make it stop at the end of the file, or will I need to specify a length to read as you have done?

Comment: @user3076673: It stops at the end for me on OS X, but I don't have a linux system to test on... is the size you're seeing from fdisk the partition size, or the device size? If it's just the partition, `xxd` may be running to the end of the device.

Comment: It is the device size.  It's not a huge issue, but what concerns me is that perhaps it's an indication of something else not functioning properly.  Really, I should be able to take "samples" from any point in the drive and check them for the existence of only one character.

Comment: @user3076673: See my edit for some suggested debugging tactics.

Answer (score 1):

I am not near my shell, but something along these lines should get you started:

```
dd if=/dev/hda1 | hexdump -C | grep [^00]
```

will print all non-zero bytes.

```
dd if=/dev/hda1 | od -x -j100
```

will give you a hexadecimal dump with offsets, starting 100 bytes in.